# WAMP: Apache not running

Tags: mysql, apache, wamp, wampserver

I have been through many pages on here that all provide solutions to this issue but am yet to find one that works for me.

I just installed Wamp (Was using Mamp. Didn't realize there was a windows specific)

Every time i try to launch Wamp, CMD pop's up very quickly and disappears. This happens so quick, i had to take a screen shot to ensure i was CMD.

Once that happens, nothing else does. Wamp does not start.

I have been through "services" and have found that mySql is running but my apache is not.

Launched CMD and searched to see what was using port 80 as from research i see that is most likely my problem. This is the result:
[CMD ScreenShot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmt9l.png)
I have NO IDEA what is listening to it. Skype is quit, World Wide Wed Services is not enabled in services. If i try and kill iis, i get an error that it is not installed.

Anyone have any ideas at all?

I was running Mamp find (On windows) but through apache 8888 and mysql 8889 as i was having the same issue.

All this to setup a multisite on wordpress..

Thank you.

Comment: To add to the above, may it be WebMatrix? I was going to use this as editor of choice and did select it as editor of choice when installing Wamp.

Comment: Try finding exe by following this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows

Comment: It was httpd.exe. This is system isn't it. This goes way over my head unfortunately. Thank you for referring that post to me. It has helped to identify.

Answer (score 0):

When PID 4 is listening on port 80 it normally means that IIS or one of its associated bits is still running

If you are not intending to use it you can uninstall it, it is not an integral part of windows so its being uninstalled wont effect normal operations of windows,
and if you need to install it again later, it comes as part of the standard OS so you wont need to do anything perticularly clever.

So go to Start -> Control Panel -> Programs and Features
Click the 'Turn windows features on and off' link in the left hand menu.
Wait for the list to load and then find 'Internet Information Services'

Un check the check boxes for the following items ( you may not see all of them ), and there may be others I done know about. You may have all of these or just some of these.

1. IIS
2. Web Deploy 2.0 (Web Deployment Agent Service)
3. MS Sql Server Reporting service.
4. BranchCache ( Windows 8.1 )
5. SQL Server VSS Writer

[List of possible service names](http://blogs.technet.com/b/fort_sql/archive/2010/05/31/list-of-sql-server-service-names.aspx) not sure how up to date this is.
[Tutorial on how to find what ports are in use on your system and what app is using them](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bgroth/archive/2004/11/11/256190.aspx)

Windows will then have a think for a while and then remove those applications, you will probably be asked to reboot to complete the uninstalls.
Reboot anyway when the uninstalls are complete.

Then try wamp again.

Alternativeley just disable it/them.

Start -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services

Find IIS in the list of services.
Left Click that line and select Properties
Change the 'Startup Type' to disabled.
Ditto for the other possibilities if you see them.